# Che cosa significa "la sua parte" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Casa d'altri* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> Erano amare parole: e mi parve che qualcosa dovessi ben dirlo a ogni modo. E mi alzai e mi avvicinai di due passi. 
>          – Era questo, Zelinda, che avevate messo nella lettera voi? 
>          – No, – disse lei: e la cosa mi stupí **la sua parte**. – No. Questo chiunque lo sa: chiunque passa lo vede, e neanche c’è bisogno di dirlo.

Non capisco cosa significhi "la sua parte" in questo passaggio. Cercando "parte" in parecchi dizionari, non sono riuscita a trovare niente che me lo possa chiarire. Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cito da Treccani alla voce [parte 2.b](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/parte/):

> Come locuz. avv., *la sua parte*, non poco, abbastanza, molto: *ha goduto anche lui la sua p. nella vita*; *è furbo la sua p., te lo dico io!*; *era un ragazzo di circa dodici anni, sveglio la sua p.* (Manzoni).

così anche il [Vocabolario della Crusca](http://www.lessicografia.it/Controller?lemma=PARTE&rewrite=1)

> §. XVI. La parte mia, o simili, posto avverbialm. vale Molto.

Answer (score 0):

Credo che significhi "un bel po'" oppure "parecchio" o "abbastanza". 
Potrebbe essere un'espressione dialettale o arcaica anche.